# Java - Recursion Program - Convert a base 10 number to any Base

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to convert a base 10 number to any base by using conversion. Right now this is the code I have came up with.  I have a sad feeling this may be completely wrong.  The image below is an example of how this process should take place.

http://i854.photobucket.com/albums/ab107/tonytauart/rrrr.png

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


  int base;
  int number;


    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the base");
        base = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Number you would like to convert");
        number = console.nextInt();

        System.out.println(Converter(base, number));
}


public static int Converter(int Nbase, int Nnumber){

    int answer;
    int Rcontainer =0;
    int cnt = 0;
    int multiplier;
    int temp;
    double exp;

    if(Nnumber/Nbase == 0){
        cnt++;
        exp = Math.pow(10,cnt); 
        multiplier = (int)exp;
         answer = (Nnumber%Nbase)* multiplier + Rcontainer;


    }
    else
      {
       exp = Math.pow(10,cnt);
       multiplier = (int)exp;
       cnt++;
       temp = Rcontainer;
       Rcontainer = (Nnumber%Nbase)* multiplier + temp;   

       Nnumber = Nnumber/Nbase;
        answer = Converter(Nbase,Nnumber);
       }  
        return answer;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, it should be labeled with the [homework] tag.

Comment: you should define a base case, let's say, when your number is less than your base, and the recursive part, let's say, the operations to get the next digit of your converted number

Comment: thanks for the heads up louis... and thanks as well luiggi, Idk why I thought having ==0 was a good idea. I don't think that is even needed now that I look at it

Comment: Are there restrictions on "any base"? For instance, are you expected to support base 900 (for which no standard character set is defined)?

Comment: I found an answer that explains how to convert an integer from any base to any other base: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15735138/975097

Comment: @LouisWasserman Two years later, yes, this is my homework.

Answer (score 14):

I just finished doing this problem for a comp sci class. I had to solve this recursively:

```
public static String convert(int number, int base)
{
    int quotient = number / base;
    int remainder = number % base;

    if (quotient == 0) // base case
    {
        return Integer.toString(remainder);      
    }
    else
    {
        return convert(quotient, base) + Integer.toString(remainder);
    }            
}
```

Comment: I think we were learning from the same book. This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 10):

```
public class Converter {

    private static char symbols[] = new char[] { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T' };

    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
                 Converter converter = new Converter ();
        System.out.println( converter.convert ( 31, 16 ));
    }

    public String convert ( int number, int base )
    {
        return convert(number, base, 0, "" );
    }

    private String convert ( int number, int base, int position, String result )
    {
        if ( number < Math.pow(base, position + 1) )
        {
            return symbols[(number / (int)Math.pow(base, position))] + result;
        }
        else
        {
            int remainder = (number % (int)Math.pow(base, position + 1));
            return convert (  number - remainder, base, position + 1, symbols[remainder / (int)( Math.pow(base, position) )] + result );
        }
    }
}
```

This will convert from Base 2 to Base 36, although you could expand it by adding more symbols.

Answer (score 3):

A quick way to do it in Java is this:

```
Integer.toString(int i,int radix);
```

For example,

```
Integer.toString(255,2)
```

would return "11111111". I'm not sure if you are just looking for a quick solution or do you actually want to implement the conversion method yourself. This would be a quick solution. Refer to this post: [What is the method in the API for converting between bases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654671/what-is-the-method-in-the-api-for-converting-between-bases)

Comment: However, the second argument defaults to 10 if given > `Character.MAX_RADIX`, which is usually 36 (10 for 0-9, 26 for alphabet) for the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to convert bases (like to base 2), try the following code:

`Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(numberToConvert,base))`

For specifically base 2:

`Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(numberToConvert))`

[Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) contains other methods such as toHexString that can be used. These assume that `numberToConvert` is in base 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Converter {

    private static char symbols[] = new char[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
                    'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T' };

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Converter converter = new Converter();
        System.out.println(converter.convert(31, 16));
    }

    public String convert(int number, int base) {
        return convert(number, base, 0, "");
    }

    private String convert(int number, int base, int position, String result) {
        if (number < Math.pow(base, position + 1)) {
            return symbols[(number / (int) Math.pow(base, position))] + result;
        } else {
            int remainder = (number % (int) Math.pow(base, position + 1));
            return convert(number - remainder, base, position + 1, symbols[remainder / (int) (Math.pow(base, position))] + result);
        }
    }

}
```