# Alphanumeric increment algorithm in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, increment, alphanumeric

I need to implement alphanumeric increment algorithm like 
AAA001 should become AAA002 
AAA999 should become AAB000 and so on.

All alphabets are in uppercase and letters are from 0-9.
It can contain alphabet or letter at any position in the alphanumeric string.

There are some rules though, like some 000 or 666 should not come in a series. That can be done later on but I am in need of basic logic to implement the algorithm.

I see many people did not understand my question. 
Just imagine the Plate Number of a vehicle which is nothing but a alphanumeric series which can have some excluded characters like BB6660 -> 666, triple 6 in between is not allowed.

It should support different formats  like-

```
    @@@##
    @#@@##
    1@#@@##
    @@@@####
    ##@@#@

    @ means alphabet A-Z
    # means numbers 0-9
```

Examples:

```
    AFG99 + 1= AFH00
    A2GF23 + 1 = A2GF24
    1A9AU99 + 1 = 1A9AV00
    AAZZ9999 + 1 = ABAA0000
    11AA9Z + 1 = 11AB0A
```

I need some sort of mathematical solution so that I can do math and increment  it easily without using character increment.

I also need the count between the two ranges like how many counts are there between AAA003 and AA010 ?

```
    AAA010 - AAA003 = 7
```

I would appreciate the help..

Comment: I think you mean the value after `AAA999` is `AAB000`, not `AAZ000`.  Also, this is not base 36 but 3 places of base 26 and 3 places of base 10.  It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.  You are expected to show us the code you have written and explain what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735079/convert-from-one-base-to-another-in-java

Comment: isnt the value after AAA999 -> AAA99A in base 36 ?

Comment: Current algorithm converts string to character and does the character increment .

Comment: Sorry, my bad. AAA999 should become AAB000. I need the algorithm in java, which increments the alphanumeric string effectively.

Comment: ok, then it is not base 36 ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, base36 means A-Z (capital or small) and 0-9 digits..!! Is that correct?

Comment: yes, but the "digit" after 9 is A.. so AAA999 would increment to AAA99A.

Comment: No ....AAA999 will become AAB000... Likewise if the string is say AZZ999 then next sequence will be BAA000

Comment: Well I have asked the question in right manner. Still why downvote? I am here to find a solution.

Comment: `I have asked the question …` Well, not formally. Neither the title nor any part of the post show the form of a question, with the possible exception of the terminating question mark. `I need some sort of mathematical solution so that I can do math and increment it easily without using character increment` You present a problem and put up constrictions that look impossible to meet: what `math` operates on mixed characters and digits?

Comment: `Current algorithm converts string to character and does the character increment` - put that in the question and explain _why_ this is inadequate. Try to end the post with an interrogative sentence, and turn the title into a question, too. If/as you are still looking for an approach (if not a problem definition), "Java" doesn't play a role (and I don't expect it when it comes to implementation). Mentioning Java in the title when the first tag is `java` is redundant - some consider it annoying.

Comment: (Come to think of it, `All alphabets are in uppercase and letters are from 0-9` reads funny - _All letters are in uppercase and digits are from 0-9_?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's 3 solutions: the first two are somewhat arithmetic incrementations while the third is more a character manipulations.

The 3 implementations all pass the same unit tests:

```
 assertEquals("1DDA01A", MyClass.increment("1DDA00Z"));
 assertEquals("1A9AV00", MyClass.increment("1A9AU99"));
 assertEquals("AFH00", MyClass.increment("AFG99"));
 assertEquals("A2GF24", MyClass.increment("A2GF23"));
 assertEquals("ABAA0000", MyClass.increment("AAZZ9999"));
 assertEquals("11AB0A", MyClass.increment("11AA9Z"));
```

**First:**

```
public static String increment(String number) {
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)([9Z]*)$");
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(number);
    String left="";
    String right="";
    if(matcher.matches()){
         left = matcher.group(1);
         right = matcher.group(2);
    }
    number = !left.isEmpty() ? Long.toString(Long.parseLong(left, 36) + 1,36):"";
    number += right.replace("Z", "A").replace("9", "0");
    return number.toUpperCase();
}
```

**Second:**

```
public static String increment(String number) {
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)([0-9]*|[A-Z]*)$");
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(number);
    String remaining = number;
    String currentGroup = "";
    String result = "";

    boolean continueToNext = true;
        while (matcher.matches() && continueToNext) {
        remaining = matcher.group(1);
        currentGroup = matcher.group(2);
        int currentGroupLength = currentGroup.length();
        int base = currentGroup.matches("[0-9]*") ? 10 : 36;
        currentGroup = Long.toString(Long.parseLong("1" + currentGroup, base) + 1, base);  // The "1" if just to ensure that "000" doesn't become 0 (and thus losing the original string length)
        currentGroup = currentGroup.substring(currentGroup.length() - currentGroupLength, currentGroup.length());
        continueToNext = Long.valueOf(currentGroup, base) == 0;
        if (base == 36) {
            currentGroup = currentGroup.replace("0", "A");
        }

        result = currentGroup + result;
        matcher = compile.matcher(remaining);
    }

    result = remaining + result;
    return result.toUpperCase();
}
```

**Third** :

This works with your current "reqs". Compared to how the question what asked at the beginning, this is not just a "left-part composed of letter" + "right part composed of digits". Now, it's "anything goes", and letters roll from A to Z to A, while digits from 0 to 9 to 0. When a letter reaches Z, it is reset to A, then the digit/letter on its left is incremented.

If all numbers are incremented, it does not add a new digit on the left. You did not mention that in your question, but I'm sure you can figure this out from here:

```
public static String increment(String number) {
    char[] cars = number.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = cars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (cars[i] == 'Z') {
            cars[i] = 'A';
        } else if (cars[i] == '9') {
            cars[i] = '0';
        } else {
            cars[i]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(cars);
}
```

As for the "count", your example isn't sufficient to grasp the logic. Does it count only numbers ? what about the letters ? Does it follow a baseXx ?

how can AA010-AAA003 = 7, the 3 A's versus 2 A's do no matter ?
I feel this is rather on you to understand what are your requirements (ie: homework..)

Technically, this answers the question as it was asked originally (with many modifications along the way).

Comment: Thanks, I have to check this.

Comment: No need to box `integerValue`.

Comment: @shmosel, thanks, I've changed integerValue  from Integer to int.

Comment: See the link -http://www.coderanch.com/t/461293/java/java/Incrementing-alphanumeric-string ..This is what my question is.

Comment: ok, then it is NOT base 36. It is some logic specific to this assignment. You should remove Base36 from your question.

Comment: why not? can't we achieve it using Base 36. I read somewhere that it is possible.

Comment: see updated answer, the last part

Comment: Thanks Alex. Let me check..

Comment: It gives AAB999 which is wrong. It should be AAB000

Comment: The second code snippet ?

Comment: yes...the second one..

Comment: Ok, i see, need to substract 11997 (999 un base 10) ill update the answer in 5min

Comment: the answer is updated

Comment: Perfect. Now I need to support different formats like 1A00001, 2BA000, 1DDA0 etc. Can it be done easily?

Comment: I'd say your requirements are not clear enough now.. :)

Comment: what do you mean 'support formats like 1A00001, 2BA000, 1DDA0' ?  1A00001 +1 = 1A00002 ?  and 1DDA0 + 1 = 1DDA1 ?  and 1DDA9+1= 1DDB0 ?

Comment: Modified to handle your other formats

Comment: Yes Alex, you got my point. Imagine a Plate Number of a vehicle. It's a alphanumeric series, right? I need to implement it.

Comment: The answer reflects that and supports these additional formats

Comment: I will check it. See my original updated post which will give you a better idea and once again thanks for helping. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It throws exception when trying to increment the string '1DDA9Z'.

Comment: your formats never had any letters on the right part... this is not in your question. and would change the answer.

Comment: here, minor tweaks and doesn't throw an exception anymore

Comment: My appologies...updated the question.. It can contain alphabet or letter at any position in the string.

Comment: Did you you try now ? It works for all formats!

Comment: I tried it. one problem. If I increment, 1DDA00Z + 1 = 1DDA010 which is not I want, please have a look at the updated question. It should be 1DDA01A. If the alphabet is Z, it should become A and if the letter is 9, it should become 0.

Comment: What makes it hard, is that your example contains errors. And then, when I provide the code, you update it.  you say "AAZZ9999 + 1 = AAAA0000", but if we follow the logic of rolling number on the left, it should be ABAA0000. the ZZ roll out on the A, which become a B (which is what your other example does : "11AA9Z + 1 = 11AB0A"

Comment: Thanks...unfortunately I already have character increment in existing algorithm..I wrote that in comment. I needed something different. May be I am a bad explanator. Marking yours as an answer for putting efforts.

Comment: I went ahead and added another solution, I believe may be closed to what you had in mind. The same unit tests still passes.

Comment: Only the third one works for `000`. It will produce `001` which is correct. First and second have parsing so will give `1`

Answer (score 0):

`[doing] math and increment [alphanumerics] without using character increment` can be decomposed into simpler problems: consider your "alphanumerics" *integers* coded with a mixed base. This would leave conversion from *alphanumeric* to *integer*, (`math`) operations (increment, *count between*: difference/subtraction) on *integers*, and conversion from *integer* to *alphanumeric*.
For *integer*, have a look at [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html). For the conversions, you need to keep a sequence of bases to use - I recommend to start from unit/the little end and just use something easily iterable and able to keep (small) integers. Going from *alphanumeric* to *integer*, start with zero. For each character, add its value. For a letter, keep the number of different letters (alphabet size, 26 with the Latin alphabet as used now) as the base to use for that place, for a digit the number of different digits (ten, usually). If another character follows, multiply by that base and repeat.
Conversion from *integer* to *alphanumeric* would be the usual [divide&remainder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#divideAndRemainder-java.math.BigInteger-) (using the bases as kept) - with a catch: how do you handle a carry from the most significant position?

`There are some rules though, like some 000 or 666 should not come in a series. That can be done later on` and will kill `math`.

Comment: What you are suggesting is partially true. I know it's difficult that is why I end up here asking for the solution.

Comment: Can you identify and describe parts that are _not_ true, in addition to presenting in no uncertain terms what is? While at it, look at the suggestions to improve your "question" (e.g., `how can AA010-AAA003 = 7, the 3 [`A`s versus 2 `A`s do not] matter?` ([Alex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38210171/3789665)))

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. It was a typo. Actually it is AAA010-AAA003 = 7.