# Reverse a Base 62 String of length 3 back to an Integer

Tags: java, algorithm

I have obtained following code to convert an Integer to a Base62 character of length 3. Is there a way I could reverse this to obtain back the initial Integer?

Example: Following code converts the Integer 238328 to "zzz" which is what I want. Is there a way I could use back "zzz" and get back the Integer 238328?

```
private static final String CHARACTERS = "0123456789"
        + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private static final int MAX_NUMBER = 238328;
private static final int BASE = CHARACTERS.length();

static String generateCode(int num) {
    if (num < 1 || num > MAX_NUMBER) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal input value: " + num);
    }

    int value = num - 1;

    char firstChar = CHARACTERS.charAt(((value / BASE) / BASE) % BASE);
    char secondChar = CHARACTERS.charAt((value / BASE) % BASE);
    char thirdChar = CHARACTERS.charAt(value % BASE);
    return new String(new char[]{firstChar, secondChar, thirdChar});
}
```

Converting the Integer 7815 gives me "222".

Was trying to reverse the above via following code which is not working.

```
static int generateNumber(){
    //hardcoding "222" to test it out
    int firstChar = 2 * BASE * BASE / BASE; 
    int secondChar = 2 * BASE / BASE;
    int thirdChar = 2 % BASE;

    return firstChar + secondChar + thirdChar;
}
```

I want to keep the generated String to be always of length 3 thus is not similar to simply converting numbers from one base to another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from one base to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735079/convert-from-one-base-to-another-in-java)

Comment: @Ben I want to keep the generated String to be always of length 3 thus is not similar to simply converting numbers from one base to another. I am looking to reverse the conversion I have now.

Comment: Why? You are simply converting it to another base and then you extend it to be of fixed length 3. The two processes have nothing to do with each other. Step 1: Convert from Base A to Base B. Step 2: Add 0 in front so you have length 3.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you. Not sure if I asked the wrong question here. I am looking to convert example "2bH" which is in base62 back to 10000. I don't get which answer on that link answers this.

Comment: `2bH` in base 62 converts to `9999` in base 10. How do you get `10000`?

Comment: And still it's just: Convert my base 62 number to a base 10 number. Which is a simple "convert from one base to another".

Comment: @Ben Its cos I am starting from 1 and not 0.

Comment: Don't you shoud do `int firstchar = CHARACTERS.indefOf(2)*.... ` instead of `int firstchar = 2*... ` ?

Comment: Also why do you do `2*BASE/BASE` it just do nothing

Comment: @vincrichaud Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this :

```
private static int generateNumber(String str){
  if(str.length() == 3) {

    char fisrtChar = str.charAt(0);
    char secondChar = str.charAt(1);
    char thirdChar = str.charAt(2);

    int firstInt = CHARACTERS.indexOf(fisrtChar) * BASE * BASE; 
    int secondInt = CHARACTERS.indexOf(secondChar) * BASE;
    int thirdInt = CHARACTERS.indexOf(thirdChar);

    return firstInt + secondInt + thirdInt + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: To make it more robust, you should add a if statement to check if every char is valid ( i.e. is inside CHARACTERS)