# How to convert big numbers from one base to another

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to convert a SQL function into Groovy for usage in Elasticsearch, but I am stuck at this stage. Considering, I have never touched java or groovy in my life, what am I doing wrong?

**CODE**

```
public String convertFromBaseToBase(String str, int fromBase, int toBase) {
    return Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(str, fromBase), toBase);
}

output = convertFromBaseToBase("8f8f87878f8f8080", 16, 10);

System.out.print(output);
```

Taken from [Convert from one base to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15735138/721553)

**ERROR**

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8f8f87878f8f8080"
>   at java_lang_Integer$parseInt.call(Unknown Source)
>   at Script1.convertFromBaseToBase(Script1.groovy:2)
>   at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`8f8f87878f8f8080` is a very big number (`10344635885392199808` in decimal), and will not fit inside an `Integer`.

You will have to use `BigInteger` for such big numbers.

```
public static String convertFromBaseToBase (String str, int fromBase, int toBase){
  return (new BigInteger(str, fromBase)).toString(toBase);
}
```

Working Code `-->` https://www.onlinegdb.com/B1mMEcKPX

BigInteger  `-->`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString(int)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Any chance, you can tell me what type is needed to use bitCount: `System.out.print(Long.bitCount(10344635885392199808 ^ 5814420315236376471));` I don't know if its groovy or java's problem, I at unfamiliar grounds in regards to both of them.
​