# Why is the xor operator producing "No signature of method" error message and / or what format does the bitCount() require to be passable?

Tags: java, groovy, xor

Ive been trying to convert a SQL function to Groovy, for usage in Elastisearch. But my knowledge of java and groovy is zero and I have been battling with all the errors, as they come by.

First problem of getting `convertFromBaseToBase` working was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138898/how-to-convert-big-numbers-from-one-base-to-another). But now I am having problems with the **XOR** operator.

Quite possibly, there is gonna be more issues after the xor part, so I'll post the full code up front:

```
public static String convertFromBaseToBase (String str, int fromBase, int toBase){
  return (new BigInteger(str, fromBase)).toString(toBase);
}

def ih_comparehash (String hash_1, String hash_2, int maxlen) { 

    String hashpart1;
    String hashpart2;

    int bitcnt = 0
    int strlen = 16
    int len = 0

    len = hash_1.length() / strlen

    for (i = 0; i < len && i < maxlen; i++) {

        hashpart1 = hash_1.substring((i * strlen) + 1, strlen);
        hashpart2 = hash_2.substring((i * strlen) + 1, strlen);

        cfbtb_1 = convertFromBaseToBase(hashpart1, 16, 10);
        cfbtb_2 = convertFromBaseToBase(hashpart2, 16, 10);

        bitcnt = bitcnt + (cfbtb_1 ^ cfbtb_2).bitCount();
    }

    return ((64 * i) - bitcnt) * 100.0 / (64 * i);
}

System.out.print(ih_comparehash("8f8f87878f8f8080", "50b0f878787a9f97", 1));
```

Pokable at: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5119420292661248

**Current error:**

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Long.bitCount() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: bitCount(long)
>   at Script1.ih_comparehash(Script1.groovy:31)
>   at Script1$ih_comparehash.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>   at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:40)

In case I have completely missed out on something, here is the function from SQL I am trying to convert into Groovy:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE hashpart1 varchar(64) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE hashpart2 varchar(64) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE bitcnt int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE strlen int DEFAULT 16;
    DECLARE i int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE len int DEFAULT 0;

    SET len = LENGTH(hash1) / strlen;

    WHILE i<len AND i < maxlen DO
        SET hashpart1 = SUBSTRING(hash1,(i*strlen)+1,strlen);
        SET hashpart2 = SUBSTRING(hash2,(i*strlen)+1,strlen);
        SET bitcnt = bitcnt + bit_count(cast(conv(hashpart1, 16, 10) as unsigned) ^ cast(conv(hashpart2, 16, 10) as unsigned));
        SET i = i+1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN ((64*i)-bitcnt)*100.0/(64*i);
END
```

Comment: What do you believe the `^` XOR operator does when applied to two strings?

Comment: @Andreas I don't know. It looks fishy, but the SQL script worked.

Comment: But the SQL doesn't do XOR on two strings, because the SQL did a `cast(xxx as unsigned)` first, converting the string to a number. Perhaps if you make `convertFromBaseToBase` return a `BigInteger` instead, you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Andreas I had that thought too, but I failed at editing the first function to instead of `toString` at the end use `toInteger`. I lack the most basic understanding of java syntax, which means any idea I get -- I don't know if my idea doesn't work or the code itself. I also tried finding substitute for `cast()` and `unsigned`, but no luck. But yes, convertFromBaseToBase returns only numbers, but error messages always say its string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL code processes chunks of 16 hex digits, because that limits the length of numeric values used in expressions to 64-bit numbers.

It then converts the 16-digit hex number into base-10, so it can cast to `unsigned`, perform the XOR and do the bitcount. The XOR is a binary operation, so the base-10 is only done for the cast, and isn't actually needed, if the SQL had a function for parsing hex numbers.

In Java, there is a class named `BigInteger` (you're actually using it) which can handle numbers of any length, so it can all be done like this:

```
public double ih_comparehash(String hash_1, String hash_2, int maxlen) {
    int len = Math.min(hash_1.length() / 16, maxlen);
    BigInteger num1 = new BigInteger(hash_1.substring(0, 16 * len), 16);
    BigInteger num2 = new BigInteger(hash_2.substring(0, 16 * len), 16);
    int bitcnt = num1.xor(num2).bitCount();
    return ((64 * len) - bitcnt) * 100.0 / (64 * len);
}
```

Or the equivalent Groovy code, if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for the work. I see your logic and I agree with it, sadly groovy has a problem: `groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.lang.Math#min.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [class java.math.BigDecimal, class java.lang.Integer] due to overlapping prototypes between:
 [double, double]
 [float, float]
 at Script1.ih_comparehash(Script1.groovy:2)
 at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)` Any ideas? I'm starting to get the feeling, that most of the issues are due to groovy..

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas It is Groovy. Try casting `Math.min((int) (hash_1.length() / 16), maxlen)` so it knows we want the `min(int, int)` overload.

Comment: To my amazement, it works! Words cannot express my gratitude! Thank you. But my experience with groovy is: Not groovy at all. (I am OK at vanilla javascript and thought java will not be much more harder.)

Comment: @KalleH.Väravas Don't blame Java for the peculiarities of Groovy.

Comment: Java is to JavaScript like Ham is to Hamster is a saying. They both look like C at first glance, but they are not alike at all.