# Java - what is the algorithm for converting decimal to any other number system

Tags: java

i'm trying to find an algorithm to convert any positive decimal number(integer) to any other number system.
I cant seem to get my head arround it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Also, the question is way too broad. At least make some clear examples and elaborate on the question, thanks.

Comment: Are the in- and output `Number`s or `String`s?

Comment: The internet is full of good tutorials and explanations how number systems work and how you can convert from one into another, even with arbitrary general systems. Please make it absolutely clear that you read through such tutorials (show research effort) and then explain what is still unclear.

Comment: Also, are you searching for a quick way of just getting this done with a program? Java supports one-line commands for number system conversions. Or are you rather interested in how to compute it on your own?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert from one base to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735079/convert-from-one-base-to-another-in-java).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can actually use the % (modulo) - operator for this purpose:
Assume you got the decimal number 123 and want to convert it to lets say binary,
you would do 123 modulo the "rank" of your desired system (in this case binary -> 2)

```
123 % 2 -> equals to 1
```

after that you divide 123 by that same "rank" and floor the result:

```
123/2 = 61.5 -> 61
```

and then repeat the process for the divisions result

```
61 % 2 -> 1
61/2 = 30.5 -> 30
30 % 2 -> 1
30/2 = 15 -> 15
```

and so on

while repeating those steps, take the result of every modulo calculation, 
and write it backwards (meaning the last result will be the very left digit, and the first result the very right digit)
you repeat those steps until you reach 0, after dividing.
so lets finish this example:

```
123 % 2 = 1 (1. digit from the right)
123/2 = 61.5 -> 61

61 % 2 = 1 (2. digit)
61/2 = 30.5 -> 30

30 % 2 = 0 (3. digit)
30/2 = 15

15 % 2 = 1 (4. digit)
15 / 2 = 7.5 -> 7

7 % 2 = 1 (5. digit)
7 / 2 = 3.5 -> 3

3 % 2 = 1 (6. digit)
3 / 2 = 1.5 -> 1
1 % 2 = 1 (7. digit)
1 / 2 = 0 <- reached zero, ending here
```

the resulting binary number for 123 would be
1111011

if you were to convert 123 to lets say hexadecimal, you would do modulo 16 and divide by 16 instead of 2

now in java i would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convertFromDec(123, 2)); //converting to binary
    System.out.println(convertFromDec(123, 8)); //converting to octal
    System.out.println(convertFromDec(123, 16)); //converting to hex
}

public static String convertFromDec(int number, int system) {
    String result = "";
    while(number > 0) {
        String digit = ""; //in case of number systems of "rank" 11 or higher
        switch(number%system) { //we would have letters from A to F as additional digits
            case 10 : digit = "A";
            case 11 : digit = "B";
            case 12 : digit = "C";
            case 13 : digit = "D";
            case 14 : digit = "E";
            case 15 : digit = "F";
            default : digit = number%system + "";
        }
        result += digit;
        number /= system;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Assuming it's your homework assignment to do this without use of Integer.toString)