# base conversion in c programming language

Tags: c, binary, decimal, radix

Could anyone point out what is wrong with this piece of code? I'm trying to write a simple(without using arrays and stuff like that) program that would convert the base 10 numbers to any other base. I'm a beginner, I've just started coding in C.

PS: As you can see I haven't written anything that would inverse the results, and I didn't receive any outputs from the compiler. It stopped working.

```
main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Please enter a number in base 10: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\nPlease enter the base that you want the number to be converted to: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    do
    {
        c=a%b;
        printf("%d",c);
        a/=b;
    }while(c!=0);
}
```

Comment: What dis you enter?  What did you get as output?  How can you change it not to print the digits in the reverse order?  When do you plan to check that the inputs worked?  When will you output a newline or blank to separate the numbers?

Comment: Well, i didn't receive any outputs, cos the compiler stopped working and yeah i haven't written anything that would inverse the result, That's all i could do...@Jonathan Leffler

Comment: I entered `42` and `8` (for octal) into your program and it replied `250` although decimal `42` is octal `52`.

Comment: Yeah that's because i haven't written anything that would reverse the result. I don't even get any results and I'm using Codeblocks to compile it.

Comment: Since you only display the result, you have nothing to reverse. You will have to find the highest-order digits in the new base first, because those are the digits that you print first. Then work your way down to the lowest-order digit.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184577/java-recursion-program-convert-a-base-10-number-to-any-base) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your while loop to a != 0.  You want to loop until you have reduced the input number to zero.  Your code is terminating when the first digit is 0.

Comment: Next challenge will be to write correctly the converted value. All digits are reserved.

Comment: Any idea on how can i inverse the result??

Answer (score 1):

CONVERT ANY BASE TO BASE 10:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{

char input[23];
int sum;
int power;
int base;
int val;
int len;
gets(input);
strupr(input);
scanf("%d",&base);
len=strlen(input);
power=len-1;
for(int x=0;x<len;x++,power--)
{
        val=input[x]-48;
        if(val>9)
        val-=7; 
        sum+=val*pow(base,power);
}
printf("%d",sum);
}
```